# reference of two "it" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, reference

> So I guess I wasn't much of a friend to him, when **it** came down to **it**, or at least had misrepresented the friend I was (From ACT)

What does the two "it" refer? I think the first "it" might be a dummy subject, but then I think it still has to represent a "real" subject, which I cannot identify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"to come down to X" is an idiom.

To understand "when it comes down to it", we first need to be familiar with the idiom. We can guess what the two "it"s refer to but a native speaker will understand it without trying to analyse the expression.

Here is an interpretation you could use to help you understand:

*So I guess I wasn't much of a friend to him, when my behaviour was reduced to its most basic form.*

However there are many other ways to fill it out, none of which are necessarily better than another.

**Answer**

Both "it"s are dummies in the sense that repeated use of the expression has removed any specific meaning to the pronouns.

---

For further information, I suggest you search online for ***come down to*** and ***come down to it***.

Here's one dictionary's explanation:

> **come down to**
>
> 1. To amount to something (usually the most important or crucial aspect of something). In this usage, "to" is typically followed by a
>    thing or idea. It's a great offer, but my decision comes down to
>    salary, to be honest with you. With rents skyrocketing, it all comes
>    down to how much you want to keep living in this part of town.
>
> [the free
> dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+down+to)